# Set var to piped findstr output and handle CRLF at end of string

Tags: batch-file, adb

Need help better understanding delayed expansion and handling CRLF at end of piped findstr output

As you can see from the blank line in output, the string from this findstr has CRLF at end. I assume this is
because (on some OS's), when piped, ["FINDSTR will automatically append `<CR><LF>` to the input."](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) )

```
adb shell ls -R /system/priv-app | findstr DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk.*
Echo -----
```

Output:

```
DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk_

-----
```

I use the below For /F to set var to command output. In the past I've always used !var!, which has the CRLF, and called a little routine to strip the CRLF. i just discovered, in this case anyway, %var% gives me the output without the CRLF! Obviously I want var to be accurate. In this usage, will %var% be correct but without the CRLF? Why is this working?

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

For /F "tokens=1*" %%G IN ('adb shell ls -R /system/priv-app ^| findstr DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk.*') DO (
    echo G="%%G"
    set var=%%G
    )
echo percent var=[%var%]
echo exclaim var=[!var!]
echo -----
exit
```

Output:

```
G="DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk_
"
percent var=[DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk_]
exclaim var=[DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk_
]
-----
```

EDIT with output of set var

```
set var
echo -----
```

returns

```
var=DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk_

-----
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the output from `echo G="%%G"`, nor the relevant output from `adb`. In all probability, there is a CR within the string being returned by `adb`. Would be useful to see the output of `set var`

Comment: @Magoo: edited with output of `echo G="%%G"` Output of set var? Not sure what you mean. In any case, think I was remembering requiring !var! when the For /F was nested, which I'm finding with further testing. Thanks for time. I will probably delete this.

Comment: It's actually interesting. Please note that the closing rabbit's ears are on a different line from the opening in `G="..."` which indicates a hidden character, probably a result of `adb` being unixy rather than dossy. `set var` will list the current values of all variables starting `var`.

Comment: @Magoo: Edited with ouput of `set var`. Well, I'm sure it's a LF...just thought findstr was adding it. I do need to nest this, so will have to strip that final char in any case. But still unclear why it doesn't show up in the %var%.

Comment: Curious - it would appear that there is an extra character after the `_` in the `adb` output. My problem is that I don't have `adb` so I can't check it. Can you output the command to a file and look at it using a hex editor?

Comment: @Magoo: Not sure. File output in Notepad++ with "all characters" turned on is:
DeviceSoftwareOTA.apk_`CR`
`CRLF`

Comment: So - seems locus of the problem is found. I'd try piping findstr output through `more` but can't test atm as my trusty editor has been upgraded.  Odd how `%var%` and `!var!` differ....

Comment: I'd try, outside of the `for` loop, `set "var=%var:~0,-1%"` and then `echo` `%var%` (I use `echo +%var%+` to place the output between two very obvious characters). This should lop off the last character of `var` which appears to be a CR. Still can't test unfortunately... I'l try whipping up a Delphi program to create a sutiable test file.

Comment: Well - after constructing a file terminating CRCRLF, it appears to be happy with `set "var=%var:~0,-1%"` and then `echo %var%`